# About the uploading my presentation video on internet and the Ethical Issues

Tags: research

I have one presentation about "*the effect of AI on music industry*" in one [academic research NGO](https://www.gicnetwork.be/the-ngo-ization-of-academic-research/) group which is created on WhatsApp, and I want to know if I publish the video of my presentation via my post about that field or  upload it on YouTube is it right (legal) and does it require any approval from the group admin or ...?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't asked for permission?

Comment: @Studoku, is there a reason you think he needs to ask permission?

Comment: Would be easier and more polite.

Comment: An excellent question if this were posted to interpersonal.SE. Here at Law.SE, it's kind of beside the point.

Comment: @bdb484  If the group has been granted an exclusive license, as is sometimes the case, permission would be required.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the linked paper as a hypothetical case, the author might have a contractal obligation with the NGO or the research institute that limits ability to freely distribute materials created "on the job", so you might have to ask your boss. Otherwise, you might think that because the material was initially recorded on WhatsApp (I surmise), there might be a requirement to get permission. So you turn to the [WhatsApp terms of service](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/updates/terms-of-service/?lang=en), in the section on licenses. The first thing they say is

> WhatsApp does not claim ownership of the information that you submit
> for your WhatsApp account or through our Services.

So you don't need their permission to redistribute material that you created using that platform.

Comment: Thanks, @user6726, so I need to have **the obligation of the NGO's Admin** for publishing the Video of the presentation on medium site or etc.

Comment: The answer says you *might* have a requirement to get permission.